# asp.net c# sort right product under right category

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting

I'm trying to render out my projects sorted under the right category. I have it right now so right product will go under right category but it doesn't render out the name. It renders out the object so it looks rather weird.

This is my code:

```
    int i = 0;
var categories = ViewBag.Category as List<Category>;
var products = ViewBag.Products as List<Product>;

foreach (var cateory in categories)
{
    i++;
        <div class="panel-group accordion" id="accordion1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse_@i">
                            @cateory.Name
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse_@i" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            @cateory.Products
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

And this is the output.

> System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[ProductCatalog.Models.Product]

I have tired this `@cateory.Products.Select(n => n.Name).ToString();` but did not do much.

Comment: ASP.NET won't automagically display a category's products. You have to add the proper rendering code just as you did with Categories. By typing `@category.Products` the only sensible thing for the compiler to do is to display the output of `category.Products.ToString()`. That is the type of the object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Correct, solved it. It's were easier than I thought.. I over think everything. hehe.